# Python fail install a github script (HLS Server loop)

Tags: python, github, stream, live, http-live-streaming

My goal it's to install a HLS server to stream a live video.
So i found https://github.com/jbochi/hls-loop this script.
But my install fail.
I am on Linux Ubuntu 14.04

`apt-get install python-dev` --> It's OK

`pip install flask` --> It's OK

`python hls-loop.py` --> ERROR python: can't open file 'hls-loop.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Also i found this packet `https://github.com/dayvson/hls-endless` but build fail too :(
If you found a another script to install HLS live stream server, , I'm more than interrested!

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you clone the repository to your local directory using:

```
git clone https://github.com/jbochi/hls-loop.git
```

Your directory structure will look something like:

```
| - <current_dir> /
|   | -- hls-loop /
|   |    | -- hls-loop.py
|   |    | -- ...
```

You have to install `Flask` using `pip` as that's a dependency for the **hls-loop** project. I'd recommend taking a look at [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) to isolate the project dependencies for each of your applications.

From your current directory you could run the application using something like `python hls-loop/hls-loop.py`. This causes and error in `read_file_durations()` due to how they are reading their static file. Because of that you will have to run the application from the same directory as the script:

```
cd hls-loop
python hls-loop.py
```

If you wanted you could create a fix for this so it doesn't matter where you run the application from by doing something like this:

```
import os


def read_file_durations():
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))
    file_durations = os.path.join(basedir, "static/bipbop_4x3/gear1/prog_index.m3u8")
    with open(file_durations) as f:
       ...
```

Hopefully that clears some stuff up for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to `git clone https://github.com/jbochi/hls-loop`, then `cd hls-loop`, then you can run `python hls-loop.py`.

Comment: I think you have mixed the first script (hls-loop and hls-endless). Same error, i don't know where "pip install flask" command install the script